# Generating unique id

Tags: java, rdbms

I was looking for information about how to generate unique no in java which I can give to customer so that they can use this no to track back their info? At the same time it should not be easily guessable. I want to implement this in java and in cluster envt.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try some sort of GUID ... i.e. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use random-number based variant (only one JDK uuid provides), Java UUID Generator (https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator) works even better.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a long as always counting upwards. Make a xor with a constant key value. The result is unique, too.